# How can I allow authenticated users to edit their nodes only while they are unpublished?

Tags: nodes

I have a site in which content must be approved by an administrator before it is published.  Authenticated users have the ability to submit content, which is unpublished by default.  I would also like to be able to have them view and edit content while it is in the unpublished state (for cases in which they realize they made a mistake and would like to correct the submission, etc.)

However, I do not want them to be able to edit the content once it is published, so I don't want to give them blanket edit permissions.

How can I allow them to edit nodes of a given content type only so long as such nodes are in an unpublished state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement a special [hook_node_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) to return TRUE or FALSE based on the node status.